# Angular Version Issue With Materials Controls

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material

My application had been running fine with the Materials libraries and suddenly now I have build errors. There seems to some mix up between my version of typescript, the CLI version, and the Materials Libraries. I keep going around in circles with this and am still very new to angular so its hard for me to make sense of things when I try to read up on these errors I am getting. The below is the output of my ng--version and ng build commands. Any help or direction offered would be greatly appreciated.

--Jason

[image]

> Error: node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/tab.d.ts:24:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MatTab' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.
> Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatTab' but required in type 'CanDisable'.

24 export declare class MatTab extends _MatTabMixinBase implements OnInit, CanDisable, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
~~~~~~

node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/disabled.d.ts:12:5
12     disabled: boolean;
~~~~~~~~
'disabled' is declared here.

Error: node_modules/@angular/material/toolbar/toolbar.d.ts:22:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MatToolbar' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'.
Type 'MatToolbar' is missing the following properties from type 'CanColor': color, defaultColor

22 export declare class MatToolbar extends _MatToolbarMixinBase implements CanColor, AfterViewInit {
~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/material/tree/node.d.ts:17:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MatTreeNode<T, K>' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.
Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatTreeNode<T, K>' but required in type 'CanDisable'.

17 export declare class MatTreeNode<T, K = T> extends _MatTreeNodeMixinBase<T, K> implements CanDisable, DoCheck, HasTabIndex, OnInit, OnDestroy {
~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/disabled.d.ts:12:5
12     disabled: boolean;
~~~~~~~~
'disabled' is declared here.

Error: node_modules/@angular/material/tree/node.d.ts:17:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MatTreeNode<T, K>' incorrectly implements interface 'HasTabIndex'.
Type 'MatTreeNode<T, K>' is missing the following properties from type 'HasTabIndex': tabIndex, defaultTabIndex

17 export declare class MatTreeNode<T, K = T> extends _MatTreeNodeMixinBase<T, K> implements CanDisable, DoCheck, HasTabIndex, OnInit, OnDestroy {
~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts:600:21 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

600 declare var global: NodeJS.Global;
~~~~~~

Comment: please share package.json

Answer (score 1):

If your code repository is maintained (GIT), then I would try to look into the history of it and see all the dependencies + devDependencies installed there, before the errors. Before going any further, I would make a new commit so that you can revert in case of failure during fixing versions and still have the newly developed code.

From the image it seems like some v11 and v12 angular packages are mixed. In semantic versioning it means MAJOR changes. In case of Angular, all the @angular scoped packages are be similarly versioned. This helps identifying compatible packages. So V11 packages are probably not compatible with V12 packages.

Then you should solve all packages to be compatible with your version, I assume your app is built around Angular V11. To find compatible package version, you can go to npmjs.com and look for each package name. In the versions tab you can see all the options available. If it is not obvious which version is compatible, then `npm i` with wrong package version should nag about it with some "peer dependency install missing" message.

Here what Angular V11.0.7 package dependencies should look like:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~11.0.7",
  "@angular/common": "~11.0.7",
  "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.7",
  "@angular/core": "~11.0.7",
  "@angular/forms": "~11.0.7",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.7",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.7",
  "@angular/router": "~11.0.7",
  "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
  "tslib": "^2.0.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.7",
  "@angular/cli": "~11.0.7",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.7",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
  "karma": "~5.1.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
  "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
  "protractor": "~7.0.0",
  "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~6.1.0",
  "typescript": "~4.0.2"
}
```

Those other packages I see in your `ng --version` listing should probably be following in the package.json dependencies:

```json
"@angular/cdk": "~11.0.4"
"@angular/flex-layout": "~11.0.0-beta.33"
"@angular/material": "~11.0.4"
```

You can also try remove the `node_modules` directory and reinstall it with `npm i`. Sometimes it helps. And try removing package-lock.json, it gets generated with `npm i` also, but it is for some reason not recommended.

If issues persists, it might be related to global package. Then I would prefer converting some of your package.json scripts to use local packages e.g:

```json
"scripts": {
  "old-start": "ng serve",
  "new-start": "npx ng serve",
  "alternative": "./node_modules/.bin/ng serve",
}
```

It should not be an issue on newer npm, but if the npm is older, it may help.